# How to automatically apply a formula each time a row is added in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Sheet set up so that a new row is added with the results each time an employee completes a review in another application. Columns C through H are number values, and I want to sum them for each individual row. So my formula for I2 (row 1 being a header) is =SUM(C2:H2). I want each row to sum automatically when it is added.

I cannot just drag the formula down because any content in the new row breaks the automation that is pulling in the data. I've tried mucking around with ARRAYFORMULA, but it isn't working (probably my fault), and frankly, I'm out of my depth.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this that will consider each row with value later on:

```
=BYROW(C2:H,LAMBDA(each,IF(COUNTA(each)=0,"",SUM(each))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved the day! I did get an error that the "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in..." I think that's because the automation was pulling *something* into that cell (even though it looked empty). But I was able to work around that by making another sheet and using a query to pull from the other, and then I was able to use your formula. It is working perfectly now!

Comment: I'm glad you could work it out!